# different columns in pivot tables according to slicer

Tags: excel

Is it possible to present different columns in a pivot tables depending on the selection in a slicer?

For example if I choose geo:US then the pivot table will show the number of population and if I select geo:Italy it will show the number of population as well as density..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not without some extensive VBA. You would have to trigger VBA from the PivotTable_Update action on the worksheet containing the pivot table, then grab the SlicerItems that are Selected from the SlicerCache object for that slicer. You could then make a decision based on the Selected SlicerItems that then changes what is in the Rows/Columns of the PivotTable.

A quick dirty example of getting Selected SlicerItems via VBA:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
    Dim sc As SlicerCache
    Dim si As SlicerItem

    Set sc = SlicerCaches("Slicer_geo")
    For Each si In sc.SlicerItems
        If si.Selected And si.Name = "US" Then
            'Monkey with the pivot table here
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```